# Primary key's all field should contain value or not?

Tags: database-theory, databases

After reading a lot of materials related to the Primary key and Unique key, I am in doubt. Let us consider a primary key (AB) in table R (ABCDE). AB together can not be null as AB is a primary key. But, is it possible for a row that A is null? Or, B is null?

Comment: yes, It is possible for "either" of them to be null but not both as both being null would make the primary key null. This further depends on whether A and B allow null values or not

Comment: Thank you @RinkeshP, but then it is going to be the same with a unique key or not? Am I wrong?

Comment: A unique key would allow at most 1 null value but a primary key won't allow null at all.